# How to generate a random value multiple of 10 within a range?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to generate a random value multiple of 10 within a range.

I have used `$urandom_range(maxVal,minVal)`, and it generates a random value within a range, but I need that value to be multiple of 10.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code:

```
$urandom_range(maxVal / 10,minVal / 10) * 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use constraints.  For example, to generate numbers between 31 and 162 which are multiples of 10:

```
module tb;

int unsigned foo;

initial begin
    repeat (8) begin
        std::randomize(foo) with {
            foo inside {[31:162]}; // min:max
            (foo % 10) == 0;       // multiples of 10
        };
        $display(foo);
    end
end

endmodule
```

Example print out:

```
   110
    70
   160
    90
   160
    70
    60
   130
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18. *Constrained random value generation*.

`$urandom_range` is great for simple conditions, but it might get cumbersome as you add more conditions.  Constraints scale well since you can keep adding a new constraint for each condition.